# Generalise Expression to slice Circulant Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have $4 \times 4 $ circulant matrix ,
$$A=A(0:3,0:3)=A(:,:)=\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
4 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 3 & 4 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
To slice second row from this matrix we have generalised expression by which we can find it by using permutation matrix and first row of matrix
for example to find second row ,
$$A(1,:)=\begin{bmatrix} 4 & 1 & 2 & 3\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $$
Similarly to find third row,
$$A(2,:)=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 4 & 1 & 2\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $$
Similarly we can use find column slices by using appropriate permutation matrix
Is there such generalised way to calculate block slices like for eg
$A(1:2,1:2)$ by using some form of permutation matrix and first row of circulant matrix